# win32gui not working with Battle.net launcher

Tags: python, win32gui

I am trying to write a program that switches between regions in my Battle.net account automatically but for whatever, win32gui functions that work fine elsewhere don't seem to work with the launcher

Here is the code

```
def show_battlenet(self):
    self._find_battlenet()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(self._battlenet, SW_SHOW)
    win32gui.BringWindowToTop(self._battlenet)
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self._battlenet)
    print(win32gui.GetWindowRect(self._battlenet))

def _find_battlenet(self):
    self._battlenet = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Battle.net")
```

It is very simple and it works just fine with other windows. But with Battle.net, it does not bring the launcher to the foreground and simply prints "(0, 0, 640, 480)" instead of the correct geometry. I wonder if there is something special about the Battle.net launcher that messes up these functions